# Limited number of users that can access a shared file in dropbox

Tags: dropbox, dropbox-api

I am using dropbox API to host my documents

Is there a limited number of users that can access simultanately to a file hosted in dropbox ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think so, no.

What do you mean when you say you're using the Dropbox **API** to host your documents? Are others accessing the document through the API somehow or just through a browser (hitting a share link)?

In the latter case, you should familiarize yourself with Dropbox's per-day bandwidth limits on share links.